# Exception / error while Profile Permission Change(Urgent)

Tags: administration, profile, permission-sets, custom-profile

[image: I am getting This Upon Saving Profile Changes]I have to change few fields in Account object to Read only at Profile level
When i am changing and Upon clicking Save, I am getting the following errors
and we have installed Service max App exchange package

And i have changed those Service max Objects As Read only or Edit to avoid this exception, but still i am getting thta exception

Any one please suggest me please,

Comment: Check the help desk of that App.  find out contact details( chat, phone etc) by visiting their app on Appexchange. Probably they are the best one to guide on App specific errors.

Comment: Is that the only Hope,